# Eclipse (Juno) doesn't show all warnings

Tags: java, eclipse

When I build the project I see 2 warnings.
When I open a layout xml file, and add a new line, save it, then I see warnings for this layout file.
Is there a way to show warnings from all source and layout files, without re-saving them to disk?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Window > Preferences. In the list select Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings and select the warnings that you want to show or ignore.